# android Database,textfields and saving form

Tags: android, textview

How to store the double value into `TextView` and set the `TextView` with `double` result. I read all the articles but couldn't locate solution please Help.
I tried this one but it didn't worked

```
int x = qtyEditText.getInputType();
int y = rateEditText.getInputType();
double tot = x * y;
amountTextView = new TextView(this);
amountTextView.setText("" + tot);
```

Comment: If any of the answers helped you, mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try: 
`amountTextView.setText(String.valueOf(tot))` ?

It works with other numeric types as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Double.toString(tot);`